# Мгновенные сообщения: оповещение на E-mail

Tags: php, mysql, логика

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо придумать и реализовать оповещение о новых сообщениях.

Мгновенные сообщения которые реализованы -  это что-то очень похожее на *Диалоги во ВКонтакте*.

Что придумал - оповещать когда есть новые сообщения:

- и человек покинул сайт больше чем 5 мин. назад;
- и установлена метка об соглашении приема таких оповещений;

Проблема в частоте оповещений.

Допустим, я отправил оповещение - при следующей проверке, cron опять его отправит - вот тут я не могу понять как правильно придумать.

После одной отправке ставить метку о том, что оповещение отправлено?

И например, каждую неделю  оповещать о том, что все-такие есть еще непрочитанные сообщения?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал работу cron'a второстепенной.

Итак, юзер написал сообщение. Ага, значит в таблице рассылок можно обновить значение даты последнего сообщения на `NOW()` и его отправку на `false` (у каждого юзера соответственно).

И собственно скрипт рассылок.

Зацикливаем скрипт на бесконечность (ну для реальных условий - минут на 10). При каждой итерации заглядываем в БД с условием "время последнего сообщения < 5 минут" и "отправка рассылки = false". Нашли запись? Отпраляем письмо и параметр "отправка рассылки" ставим на `true`.

Вот так всё просто :) Про баги относительно sql подключений и баги с работой cron'a думаю достойны отдельных топиков.

Ах да, совсем забыл про оповещение о сообщениях каждую неделю: тут тоже самое, только вместо цикла будет происходить одна итерация. При том еще нужно добавить условие к существующему запросу: "если отправленное сообщение не прочитано". Но я бы не стал добавлять данную штуку в проект.